# How do prevent a directory to upload

Tags: google-app-engine

How do I prevent files  in a specific directory from uploading to Google AppEngine, while still uploading some (or all)  of it's subdirectories.

I have tried:

```
skip_files:
^/source/source/[^/]*
```

with no success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the directory is not in the root of your project then this should work:

```
(.*/source/source/.*)
```

for a directory in the root of you project try this:

```
(source/source/.*)
```